# Limiting the number of variables that one can use in foswiki

Tags: security, mediawiki, twiki, foswiki

Can I somehow limit the number of variables that a user can have access to somehow like setting up read/write/delete permissions for other users.

Comment: I think this is a programming question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot limit the number of variables or macros for a user.